# setTimeout working fast

Tags: javascript

```
 var k=0;var n=0;
  function shiftrigh(){
  n=n+1;
  if(n<=193)
   window.setTimeout(shiftright(),100);
  else
      n=0;}

function shiftright(){
   k-=1;
   document.getElementById("abcmngcontainer").style.left=k+"px";
   window.setTimeout(shiftrigh(),100);
}

function shiftlef(){
  n=n+1;
  if(n<=193)
   window.setTimeout(shiftleft(),100);
  else
      n=0;}

function shiftleft(){
   k+=1;
   document.getElementById("abcmngcontainer").style.left=k+"px";
   window.setTimeout(shiftlef(),100);
}
```

Hi, I have the above code. The function `shiftrigh` when called invokes `shiftright` and then a cycle 
is created then goes on until `n` is `193`. Same is the case for the `shiflef` pair.
The code is working but it is working pretty quick. Whether I decrease the time value in settimeout or increase it, it remains the same. The updates are pretty quick, not smooth enough to see.

Comment: You are not calling the funtion after the time, you are calling **the result of the function**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
window.setTimeout(shiftright(),100);
```

to:

```
window.setTimeout(shiftright,100);
```

Note the missing parens. The same with `shiftleft()` -> `shiftleft`.

This is a common misunderstanding in JavaScript. `setTimeout()` requires a reference to a function (`shiftright`). What you are doing is calling that function immediately and passing whatever was returned from it to `setTimeout()`. Clearly not what was intended.

Comment: wow! that was pretty fast. thanks a lot. My concept was really wrong. But I had used it before and it had worked. Now i see why it worked earlier and  why not now. Thanks for edifying me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `window.setTimeout` wrong!

```
window.setTimeout(shiftlef(),100);
```

You have to pass a function reference, not the return code of the function.
So the right version looks like this:

```
window.setTimeout(shiftlef,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` will need a function-NAME or a function-"variable"/"pointer" as first argument...

in your code, you pass the RETURN value of your function-call as first parameter to "setTimeout"....

just remove the braces ->

`window.setTimeout(shiftleft, 100)`